# Getting " Portlet Portlet_WAR_portletID has a null portlet bag" in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I created a liferay plugin portlet project and deployed in Liferay 6.2. When i try to deploy, i am getting " `Portlet Portlet_WAR_portletID` has a null portlet bag" error. I am not able to find the root as i could see i am referring correct plugin project.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContextFactory._create(PortletContextFactory.java:84)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContextFactory.create(PortletContextFactory.java:40)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletConfigFactoryImpl.create(PortletConfigFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletConfigFactoryUtil.create(PortletConfigFactoryUtil.java:32)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:606)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:78)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl._doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:655)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:138)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:141)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:156)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:120)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.access$4(PortletRenderer.java:107)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:174)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer$PortletRendererCallable.doCall(PortletRenderer.java:1)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.executor.CopyThreadLocalCallable.call(CopyThreadLocalCallable.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:682)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:593)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6):

Redeploy your portlet again. I faced same issue. I stop server and then clean my portlet then I started my server. When I checked in browser then I got internal server and in console "
portlet contains a null bag". I deployed again and the it is coming perfectly.

Comment: I can confirm - removing my portlet from webapps in liferay's tomcat folder and then deploying it again solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution for this problem is that just undeploy the portlet from the tomcat and redeploy it.